# local rotations of complex functions at roots

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose I have $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with a root at $r$, and I want to make a $g(z)$ for which $r$ is also a root but $\lim_{z\rightarrow r} g(z)/f(z) =e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$

For example take $f(z)=z^{4}-1$, for which there is a phase portrait on the left below. (was generated with [mpmath and matplotlib](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/)). The image on the right was made by applying the gimp's swirl option in the Iwarp distort to the root at $1$ -- consider it the phase portrait of $g(z)$:

- How does one construct $g(z)$ from $f(z)$ with prescribed rotations at each root?

[image]

Comment: What about $g(z):=f(z)\cdot e^{i\theta}$?

Comment: @Berci: That changes the phase of the entire function and not at any particular root.

Comment: If you know the root $r$, you can take $g(z) = f(r + e^{i\theta}(z-r))$. Not sure if that's what you want, though.

Comment: Are your functions required to be complex analytic?

Comment: @bryanj: I would prefer they be. The motivation for this question were the two lacunaries $A(q)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac{q^{2^{n}}+q^{n^{2}}}{1-q^{2^{n}}}\right)$ and $B(q)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1 - q^{n^2} - 2q^{2^{n}}\right)$ which share the same set of roots but have different phases in the vicinity of each root. I couldn't see an easy way to modify the phases at the roots independently so I started looking at the toy example of the quartic above and was still stumped.

Comment: I wonder if the Uniqueness theorem for analytic functions prevents rotating near the roots locally without significantly changing the function away from the roots. The pictures you provided make it look like the function is only changed in a neighborhood near the root - you can't do that with analytic functions.

Comment: @deoxygerbe - Do those two functions differ significantly away from the zeros? I mean - do the two pictures *appear* like the only difference is near the zeros?

Comment: @bryanj: if you're around, let's take this to chat?

Comment: @bryanj: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post this as a comment, but it was too long. I'm not certain it does what is required, so I'll be happy to delete if it's not helpful.

**Possibility #1: If $f(z)$ is analytic and you want $g(z)$ to be analytic:**
If you want to rotate $f(z)$ at a finite number of roots $r_1, r_2, \cdots, r_n$, and you want to rotate by $a_k$ at root $r_k$, you might be able to use $g(z) = L(z) f(z)$, where $L(z)$ is a [Lagrange polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).
$$L(z) = \sum \limits _{j = 1}^n a_k \frac{(z - r_1)(z-r_2)\cdots \widehat{(z-r_k)}\cdots(z-r_n)}{(r_k - r_1)(r_k-r_2)\cdots \widehat{(r_k-r_k)}\cdots(r_k-r_n)}$$
where $\widehat{(z-r_k)}$ and $\widehat{(r_k-r_k)}$ means those factors are not included in the product.
I think $L(r_k) = a_k$, and so at each root $r_k$
$$
  \lim \limits _{z \to r_k} \frac{g(z)}{f(z)}
   = \lim \limits _{z \to r_k} \frac{L(z) f(z)}{f(z)}
   = \lim \limits _{z \to r_k} L(z)
   = a_k
$$

**Possibility #2: $g(z)$ does not need to be analytic:** Let $B(r_k, \delta_k, z)$ be a bump function with compact support near a root $r_k$ with $B(r_k, \delta_k, r_k) = 1$ and $B(r_k, \delta_k, z) = 0$ when $|z - r_k| > \delta_k$.

Outside all $|z - r_k| < \delta_k$ disks let $g(z) = f(z)$.

Inside a $|z - r_k| < \delta_k$ disk let $g(z) = \Big[a_k B(r_k, \delta_k, z) + (1- B(r_k, \delta_k, z) ) \Big] f(z)$.